# HP Quality Center Status plugin Hudson or Sonar

Tags: plugins, jenkins, hudson, sonarqube

Does anyone have any idea about a plugin for Hudson or Sonar that connects to HP Quality Center and retrieves a status about the opened DEFECTS in a project?

Comment: Seems like the real concern is hitting Quality Center rather than Hudson or Sonar?  Perhaps you'd need a specific utility user that has access to QC and won't have its password expire?

Answer (score 2):

There's currently no plugin for HP Quality Center, but it shouldn't be too hard to develop one.

You can have a look at the source code of the JIRA plugin to see how this could be achieved: https://github.com/SonarCommunity/sonar-jira